# How to create list, when a value choosen, cells values in column change

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 2 worksheets, one is having list of values and other having data. I have 3 lists in 3 columns.

```
List1 
1
2
3
4

List2
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8

List3
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
```

I want to create list from above values. In the first sheet, i want to show List1, List2, List3 as selection list. Depending on the value of the cell selected, it should populate the list in the cells.

Comment: Then do so. What is your question? What are you not getting?

Comment: I have created, 3 tables for the above mentioned values. Now i want to show List1, List2, List3 as Pick from drop down list and depending on the value selected I have to show the values. So say, if i select List1, then the values should be displayed in that many rows. I don't know, how to do it...! Also no macro is allowed here... :(

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: I am using Excel 2016

Comment: Give us the example of what you want the output will be. A screenshot is always be more useful.

Comment: @vylix, he simply wants to use Data validation to pull the content of various cells, and put them in a drop-down list. If I have some free time tomorrow, I'll write you up an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Select the cell you want to create a list for.

Go to the tab Data, and find the button Data validation. Its next to Text to columns.

Press it.

Below Allow, select List.

Click Source once.

Now on your sheet, make a selection. It should enter the range in your data validation window.

Press OK.

Your cell is still empty, but it now has a drop-down arrow next to it. Clicking it will show the list linked to the other cells.

Editing the sheet will alter the list, but not its dimension. So a new item at the bottom in between will cause the list to become incomplete, and it will have to be redefined.

You can combat this by defining a custom range for the list and refer to this custom range. As a result, everytime you edit the dimensions of the list, you only need to redefine the custom range once, not find every cell that has this custom list attached to it.

Comment: I want output like below image...
<img src="C:/test/Capture.png" width="100" height="100">